# Want to install MySQL 5.7 but apt-cache policy mysql-server not showing mysql 5.7 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-22.04, mysql5

I have some trouble on installing mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 22.04

I follow this steps https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-focal/

I checked that I have followed correctly, but on the steps to search for MySQL 5.7 using apt-cache command below

`sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server`

I get below result, which is missing the 5.7 mysql version

[image: apt-cache policy mysql-server]

I tried to reconfigure by using this command below

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config`

In which I select this first selection

[image: first selection]

then I select this second selection

[image: second selection]

then I select okay

[image: select ok]

but open check again using
`apt-cache policy mysql-server`

it's still same missing mysql 5.7

Notice the error

```
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

I have also try running mysql purge as below

`sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config`

then reinstall the apt repository but the mysql 5.7 list still not appear

[image: missing mysql 5.7]

I found many solution posted are related to people had problem like this with mysql 8.0 installation but I am unable to found someone that had problem like this one I asked related to mysql 5.7 thus asking for help here

Any help is kindly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to solve this issue

Apparently the issue happened due to this error when apt update

`"signature couldn't be verified" error like this one: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29`

To fix this I run the below command

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29`

Found the fixture by reading this - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu/